# No vertices, edges or faces displayed

Tags: vertices, edges, faces, theme

I am new to blender and I have been trying to follow along to Blender Guru's How to make a teddy bear video but when I got to the part where I need to make seams, I don't have that same pathway choice as him. I can't see any of the faces, vertices or edges. My theme is also getting in the way as whenever I click on a toolbar option, the options seem to other lap. Does anyone know how I can fix this?[image]

Comment: Hello :). Judging from the slightly broken UI, I'd say it's a hardware issue. What's your GPU?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem, I didn't have any GPU on my laptop so i swapped to another one, which does ! This one has Intel (R) Iris (TM) , thank you so much for your help! :)